# How to export coordinates of selected nodes with ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap

In ArcMap, I imported a .shp file with .dbf file.  In the .dbf file, there is an attribute that denotes the node type. In ArcMap, by the menu "Selection > Select by Attributes", I chose the nodes that I want. The nodes chosen became light-blue.

Now, how can I export the location coordinates of the chosen nodes with their node names? The node names are attributes recorded in the .dbf file.

This is my first time to use any GIS software, so please be patient.

Comment: The nodes are points, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need firstly to add coordinates for all points in the attribute table (.dbf file). It is in [ArcToolbox](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_EcF6zipHCxg/THapwM3T92I/AAAAAAAAADE/mj50tXKZHU0/s1600/5.bmp) > Data Management toolbox > Features toolset > Add XY Coordinates (see help for ArcGIS [9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=add_xy_coordinates_%28data_management%29) or [10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000032000000)). Then you can do your selection.

Then you can open the Attribute table ([right-click on the layer](http://gis.little-yeti.com/tuts/combine/combine03.jpg)) and copy selected lines to Notepad or Excel (right-click on the left side of the table and Copy selected).

Or you can click on the button Options at the low-right corner of the Attribute table and Export the table asking only Selected features. In that new .dbf table you will have only those points which you selected, and you can open it in Excel and see your coordinates.